# Nested attributes showing 'nil' in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, wizard, formwizard

Been stuck on this for a while, I am using wizard gem and looking to save  tenants attributes in a nested form. The attributes are being saved but are outputting nil in the database. Cant seem to understand why not sure if its the gem or, I am missing something obvious in the model or controller.

Parameters

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xPqiDsUpnuLHCSnU+XuAUce4b/cTnM/gv6T7wxdIz4g=", "property"=>{"tenants_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"Mr", "firstname"=>"Foo", "surname"=>"bar", "dateofbirth(1i)"=>"2013", "dateofbirth(2i)"=>"7", "dateofbirth(3i)"=>"21", "telno"=>"01143268375", "contact_type"=>"foo", "email"=>"example@gmail.com"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Tenant", "property_id"=>"58"}
```

here is the log showing tenant attributes as nil.

```
 INSERT INTO "tenants" ("contact_type", "created_at", "dateofbirth", "email", "firstname", "property_id", "surname", "telno", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["contact_type", nil], ["created_at", Sun, 21 Jul 2013 10:53:00 UTC +00:00], ["dateofbirth", nil], ["email", nil], ["firstname", nil], ["property_id", nil], ["surname", nil], ["telno", nil], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Sun, 21 Jul 2013 10:53:00 UTC +00:00]]
```

properties/build Controller

```
class Properties::BuildController < ApplicationController


    include Wicked::Wizard 
    steps :tenant

    def show
      @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
      @tenant = @property.tenants.new
      render_wizard
    end

    def update
     @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
         @tenants = Tenant.find(params[:tenant])
        case step
      when :tenant 
        if @tenants.update_attributes(params[:tenants])
         render_wizard @tenant
        else
         render :action => 'edit'
        end
    end
end

def create
    @tenant = Tenant.create
    if @tenant.save
        flash[:success] = "Tenant Added"
        redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first, :tenant_id => @tenant.id)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

end

property model

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name, :address_attributes, :tenants_attributes
  belongs_to :user 

  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  validates_associated :address

  has_many :tenants
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tenants



  validates :name, presence: true,  length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

end
```

Tenant form

```
<h2> Tenant Form</h2>


<%= simple_form_for @property, :url => url_for(:action => 'create', :controller =>   'properties/build'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :tenants do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :firstname %>
  <%= f.input :surname %>
  <%= f.input :dateofbirth %>
  <%= f.input :telno %>
  <%= f.input :contact_type %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors in your view. First, you are missing an end statement. Second, you are using f for the outer and inner form, so you are overriding outer with the inner. Try something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @property, :url => url_for(:action => 'create', :controller =>   'properties/build'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>
  # Fields for property (f.input...)
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :tenants do |tenant| %>
    # Fields For tenant (tenant.input...)
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also, I think you have an error here

```
@tenant = Tenant.create
if @tenant.save
  flash[:success] = "Tenant Added"
  redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first, :tenant_id => @tenant.id)
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

When using `if something.save`, you must use `something.new` before it instead of `something.create` (`create` creates new record and saves it to the database, to there is no need to save it again, and `new` just creates the record, but you must save it manually).

You probably need something like

```
@property = Property.new(params[:property])
if @property.save
  flash[:success] = "Tenant Added"
  redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first, :tenant_id => @tenant.id)
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip made those changes.

Comment: Unfortunately not still having the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the html which is being generated by your simple form?

Comment: it's quite long so i pasted it on pastie, please take a look here. http://pastie.org/8160970

Comment: You also must have name, address and user_id because you are validating them as present (they are mandatory if presence is true).

Comment: These are all validated in another simple form, tenant is like the second step in a multi-page form. let me know if you want me to see that form too.

Comment: It would be better if you could paste a part of the log regarding one specific request (from rails server log).

Comment: Here is the specific request for the add property form, bit long again. so posted it on http://pastie.org/8161144

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, Tried with both create and new, same issue, just wont save the records.

Comment: Call `logger.info @property.attributes` after `.new` statement and paste output of the rails server log.

Comment: Here it is http://pastie.org/8161655, It finally worked, You was right in your edit to the question, I kept substituting @property to tenant, as I thought that was relevant to the tenant attributes. Feel like an idiot. Really appreciate the help and the patience. Certainly wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: You are welcome. Be sure to check http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 for details on how nested attributes and forms work. Greetings.